# CSS3: Ayuda con width en etiqueta label

Tags: css3

Muy buenas. Tengo un problema para entender lo siguiente:
Tengo una etiqueta "label" a la que le aplico un ancho de 230px, al ser "label" una etiqueta inline no ocurre ningún cambio, ok, hasta ahí todo bien.[image: Imagen1]

Lo que no entiendo es, ¿por qué al aplicar la propiedad "float:left" , el ancho de 230px se hace efectivo? 
[image: Imagen2]

Ya sé que el ejercicio puede parecer absurdo, estoy aprendiendo CSS3 por mi cuenta y me surgió esta duda. 
Gracias anticipadas por la ayuda.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 label{
  width: 230px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;

 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <label for="texto">Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" id="texto">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido al Sitio Esteco , por favor sería genial que añadiera el código en formato texto y no en imágenes. además como recomendación [realizar el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona el sitio. Gracias.

Comment: es algo mas de CSS 2.x fijate este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/q/38464859/1423096

Comment: Gracias alo Malbarez!  Duda resuelta.

Comment: @aloMalbarez con esa información se podría elaborar una buena respuesta para esta pregunta. ¿Te animas a crearla?